24.04 Server NFS-v2 server - can't get it to work
I upgraded from 22.04 LTS (x86_64) where I had NFS v2 server working (see advice from several older posts).  I tried several suggestions to force v2 via various config files.
I need to serve firmware files via NFS v2 to some embedded devices which cannot be upgraded.
If there is no fix, can anybody recommend a user-space NFS Server that can speak v2. This is NOT a very demanding application, no security concerns, it only needs to make a few files available for the device to boot.

I managed to get nfsv2 to work.
To achive this I needed to recompile the installed kernel with CONFIG_NFSD_V2 set to yes.
Have a look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
I followed theses instructions more or less.
And I manually compiled the nfs-utils cloned via git and reverted the commit, which removed the vers2 setting in the nfs.conf.
After that, I could use my desktop with our old embedded devices to boot from.
Git Repo: git://git.linux-nfs.org/projects/steved/nfs-utils.git
Git Commit which I reverted: 2c2c36c59fa1de2ff7fd28917e54700ecb39b730
Hope this helps you, to get your clients back up ....
But anyways, this is just a momentary solution as your updates will stop working.
Get the embedded device updated or exchanged :).
